# Jenkins can not run build Script

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins job set for an IOS Project clones (fetches) the code from Bitbucket but fails to run one of the last scripts for building the Xcode project.
The script is called.I get the following error it really does not mean a lot for me.
Has anyone had a similar problem.I am pretty sure that there is something wrong with the project settings since other jobs in the jenkins run perfect.

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script 
/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-Workspace-doqiapyymubizteljhyzayqxdtyk/Build/Intermediates/Target.build/Release-iphoneos/Target.build/Script-334A8A5117785D7D001DC5DA.sh
cd "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/myApp - BETA"


/bin/sh -c /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myDriveriOSDriver-Workspace-  doqiapyymubizteljhyzayqxdtyk/Build/Intermediates/Driver.build/Release-iphoneos/Driver.build/Script-334A8A5117785D7D001DC5DA.sh
fatal: Not a git repository: '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/myApp - BETA/../.git'
VERSION: 2.1.3.0
2014-01-24 13:54:29.529 defaults[61460:507] Unexpected argument Driver; leaving defaults  unchanged.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED ** 


 The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-  Workspace-doqiapyymubizteljhyzayqxdtyk/Build/Intermediates/Target.build/Release-iphoneos/Target.build/Script-334A8A5117785D7D001DC5DA.sh
(1 failure)
```

The mentioned script sets some environment variables before the fatal error including;

```
...
setenv YACC yacc
setenv arch armv7s
setenv variant normal
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear error in the log:

fatal: Not a git repository: '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/myApp - BETA/../.git'

Comment: yes but it does not make much sense because the rep. contains the .git file if check it from bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing your error log I guess that problem is in following statement

> cd "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/myApp - BETA"

instead try

> cd "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/myApp\ -\ BETA"

hope it helps